# Есть ли ошибки в данных примерах?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

1) Он ни бедный ни богатый. Он ни беден ни богат.

2) Он не бедный, но и не богатый. Он не беден, но и не богат.

3) Он не бедный и не богатый. Он не беден и не богат.

4) Он и не бедный и не богатый. Он и не беден и не богат.

Везде ли НЕ -раздельно? А может, где надо НИ  поставить вместо НЕ? Запятые нужны?

Answer (score 1):

Мне больше нравится так:

1) Он ни бедный ни богатый. Он ни беден ни богат.

2) Он не бедный, но и не богатый. Он не беден, но и не богат.

3) Он не бедный и не богатый. Он не беден и не богат.

4) Он и не бедный, и не богатый. Он и не беден, и не богат (поставлены запятые). При наличии двух видов союзов здесь уже нет тесного смыслового единства

Answer (score 0):

Везде, кроме 3), нужны запятые (таково свойство оборотов с двойным утверждением или отрицанием - "и..., и..." и "ни..., ни..."). Остальное правильно. "Не" раздельно ввиду прямого смыслового отрицания качества, в отличие от случая характеристики чьего-то скромного достатка: он был небогат (это был небогатый помещик).